# 301 Redirect and Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following code which is working perfectly for rewriting and redirecting

domain.com/pais.php?nombre=Andorra to domain.com/Andorra/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+pais\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&|\?)nombre=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%2/? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /pais.php?nombre=$1 [L]
```

What I need to do know is do the same thing with

```
domain.com/ciudad.php?nombre=Andorra&ciudad=Andorra+La+Vella
```

it should go to

```
domain.com/Andorra/Andorra+La+Vella/
```

I'm not sure how to use 2 variables in rewrite condition.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need another set of rules, but the longer one just needs to come first:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+pais\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&|\?)nombre=(.*)&ciudad=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%2/%3/? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)/$ /pais.php?nombre=$1&ciudad=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+pais\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&|\?)nombre=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%2/? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /pais.php?nombre=$1 [L]
```